# Configure Solr Index With File Metadata using TikaEntityProcessor & FieldStreamDataSource

Tags: asp.net, sql, solr, apache-tika

I have created an index that pulls data from a SQL Server database using TikaEntityProcessor. The query associated with my configuration file pulls from a table containing file information, as well as the file content as a binary column. My index returns all fields from the database table in which I have configured, as well as the column for "text" that is the body of the file content. It correctly indexes the file text! However, the meta columns are not working! You can see I have a field for text/body, this works fine. However, I cannot get any metadata from the file such as last modified date or author.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!

### **data-config:**

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
              driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
              url="jdbc:sqlserver://server;databaseName=db1;integratedSecurity=false"
              user="user"
              password="XXXXXX" convertType="false"
              name="ds"/>

  <dataSource name="fieldReader"
  type="FieldStreamDataSource"  />

  <document name="tika">
    <entity name="tika" pk="id" transformer="TemplateTransformer" dataSource="ds"
                query="select id, title from myDatabaseTable">
      <entity name="tika-test" processor="TikaEntityProcessor" dataSource="fieldReader"
          dataField="tika.FileContent" format="text">
        <field column="text" name="body"/>
        <field column="Last-Modified" name="lastModified" meta="true" /> <!-- not working -->

      </entity>
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

### **schema:**

```
<field name="id" type="integer" indexed="true" stored="true"  /> 
<field name="body" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="lastModified" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" /> 
<field name="title" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Isn't the "last modified" field in the metadata called just `modified`?

Comment: Not sure, I will try it out. Could you direct me to info on the meta column names? I would like to get author and few others too, but not sure what the column names should be. Thanks!!!